# R thinks argument is a function but actually is a variable

Tags: r, function

In the RShiny package (for web applications) you have reactive variables (update automatically when something in the UI changes). When you use these variables you need to use this syntax: `variable()` with brackets at the end of the variable name.

I need this reactive variable as input for one of my functions. I call this function in the `server.R` part. There I use function(`infile = fa_archive(), ...`) but R thinks that `fa_archive()` is a function instead of a variable. Probably because of the parentheses, but it isn't. I am 100% sure the variable `fa_archive` is defined. Beforehand I only needed `fa_archive[[1]]()` as input and then my function worked fine. But now I needed to "upgrade" my function as to include more files at once and when I use `fa_archive()` as input variable in the function it recognizes it as a function and returns

> Error: Could not find function "fa_archive()"

I have not really tried solving this, because it just seems so weird that using the full variable instead of a part of it (`[[1]]`) should change this so drastically. Here is  the relevant piece of my code

```
fa_archive <- list( 
                  reactive({ fa_archive_function(input$model1, as.integer(input$lag1)) }),
                  reactive({ fa_archive_function(input$model2, as.integer(input$lag2)) }),
                  reactive({ fa_archive_function(input$model3, as.integer(input$lag3)) }),
                  reactive({ fa_archive_function(input$model4, as.integer(input$lag4)) }))


output$plotSounding1Da <- renderPlot({ plot_profile(infile= fa_archive() , fcdate=fcdate(), ldt=ldt(), prm=input$prmSounding, location=input$location, recent=recent(), add=FALSE)}, width=400, height=500)
```

Comment: What if you use `fa_archive` instead of  `fa_archive()` in `renderPlot(...)`

Comment: ```Error : invalid 'file' argument``` , So does not work.

Comment: ```renderPlot({ plot_profile(infile= fa_archive[[1]](), ... })``` works to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

> When you use [reactive] variables you need to use this syntax: `variable()` with brackets at the end of the variable name.

Correct. But this *only* works on a `reactive` variable. And your `fa_archive()` isn’t a `reactive` variable, it’s a normal R lits. That’s why R complains.

Just surrounding the `list` call with `reactive(…)` probably won’t work though, because your code has other issues that need fixing. Without knowing what exactly `plot_profile` does, it’s unlikely that it expects a list of `reactive` components as an argument.

Comment: Well okay, but then why does ```fa_archive[[1]]()``` work though? the plot_profile does need a variable that "changes", because in the UI if you change an input model you want a different plot to appear on  your screen. I mean everything worked fine until I just changed this little detail.

Comment: @CFRedDemon Because I’m wrong: `renderPlot` implicitly accepts a reactive expression. But the issue then is that your `fa_archive` *isn’t* a reactive variable, so you can’t use it as one.

Comment: Oh, and it has a lot of other reactive input variables too, like the date() etc... that have never in the history of this code made any trouble

Comment: Oh okay I see, indeed only the elements of the list fa_archive are reactive. Thanks a lot!